# Need to show image when validation summary control triggered

Tags: asp.net

I have a Warning Image(gif). I want to show this image only when `Validation Summary control` triggered. Any way to display this Image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show an image through `CssClass` attribute but I'd suggest the [jQuery](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/) plugin.

```
.TestClass
{
     background:url(warning.png) no-repeat ;
     padding:3px 10px 3px 10px;
}
```

Markup

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="TestClass"
    .....
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Above example from.. below reference link

http://weblogs.asp.net/alnurismail/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-a-validationsummary-with-some-style.aspx

Please, take a look to below articles.. for more information and examples...

http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/12/showing-image-when-validation-fails.html

http://aspnetresources.com/blog/pimpin_validation_summary_with_css